# Remote MS Sql server backup and restore from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, remote-server

I am trying to create a c# function that will backup and restore an mssql server 2005 db. I have tried almost everything on the net but I have no luck. On my local machine everything works perfect, but when I tried remotely I take the error:Operating system error 3... BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. Iam using Server.MapPath("~/mypath") for the path. I have also tried the following, with no luck:
[Tranferring backup files from a remote sql server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33963/Transferring-backup-files-from-a-remote-SQL-Server)

Comment: Can you provide the SQL it is running? How are you logging into the database server? If youre using a trusted connection does your user have permission to write to the backup location?

Comment: The destination directory for the backup command should be a local directory of the remote server.

Answer (score 3):

```
Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

You should use a local directory on the remote server to save the backup
(of course the user connected should have permission to reach that local directory)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using a public access directory. To test I am using the directory I host my site. For example Server.MapPath("~/john")
John is a folder on my site

Comment: Probably the Server.MapPath doesn't resolve correctly. Could you check the output of that command when executing the backup?

Comment: I also used UNC path, but with no luck

Comment: Well, something should be wrong on that path. SqlServer runs with a specific account like LOCALSYSTEM or NETWORKSERVICE, but if it was a permission problem then you should get an Error 5 Access denied.

Comment: I am running the tests from a sub domain, but the Server.MapPath("~/john") finds exactly the directory. I can see this from the error I take.
. The sub domain can cause the problem?

Comment: I don't know about subdomains. How are you running your app on the remote server? Through ASP.NET process?

Comment: yes. And localy via visual studio 2008. I tried to live site(not to subdomain) and i have the same result.

Comment: The error:
Cannot open backup device 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\my_site_name\test_folder\my_back.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Could you suggest me a source to look and read more, about  remote backup.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help. It should work as is providing the folder exists and the user executing the command has permissions. Perhaps in Sql Profiler there is some info to check, but this requires an administrative access (remote desktop or similar) to the remote machine.

Comment: As a different approach. Could you create the command in a Stored procedure on the remote server and try to call the proc? Just to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I did it. The procedure gives the bak locally but remotely no.